# Trademark designer's surname is indexed incorrectly

Tags: search, google-patents, usd3003

In reference to patent [US D3,003](https://www.google.com/patents/USD3003).

How did the name of the trademark designer/patent applicant come to be indexed as J. H. Gaknhart, since in the text of the trademark application it is clear his surname was Garnhart?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Ask Patents! Google Patents uses image recognition (OCR) to understand patent text. Especially on older patents, where text was less formalized, it sometimes makes mistakes like this. I've linked above to the steps for correcting errors on Google Patents.

Comment: I'd like to reopen this question because it provides an instructive example for search. It is true that this was due to an OCR error, but I don't believe it qualifies as a duplicate.